# UIImage view do not have integer height with autolayout, drawn line gets blurry

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-graphics, cgcontext

I am trying to make a simple drawing app for the iPhone. Everything worked fine, until I attempted the layout.

My Imageview should have a fixed aspect ration of 3:4, because of iPhone picture format. I also pinned it to the top layout guide and to the sides.

The lines I draw are being distorted, and "flow away"

[image: flowing lines - screenshot]

The closer I get to the bottom end of the view, the more the line gets pulled upwards.

I read somewhere that it could be caused by the view receiving a height that is not an integer after the autolayout, which seems to be true:

[image: rect measurements and autolayout constraints]

I don't want to hardcode the rect for every iOS device.

**How can I "round away" this 0.5 in the height?**

Here is my draw line method:

```
func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

    // 1
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempImageView.frame.size)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tempImageView.frame.size.width, height: tempImageView.frame.size.height))


    // 2
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y)

    // 3
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1.0)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)

    // 4b
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    // 5
    tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    tempImageView.alpha = opacity
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

}
```

I already tried to switch of antialising, but that didn't help, it just made it look horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a canvas with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, it's default scale is 1. This may cause the generated image to be not clear enough for display on a retina screen.

So you need to specify the scale obviously, either specify you desired scale, or specify 0, to let screen decide the scale.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tempImageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
```